# EclipseLink and log4j: how to use both

Tags: java, log4j, eclipselink

I'm using Eclipselink JPA provider, and noticed that it writes in console only. 
I configured both the console and file appenders, but EclipseLink log entries (SQL queries for example) are appeared only in the console log. 
How to fix it?

Here is my log4j configuration:

```
log4j.rootLogger=ALL, FILE, CONSOLE

log4j.logger.uk.co.mycompany=DEBUG

log4j.logger.org.eclipse.persistence=ALL

log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender 
log4j.appender.FILE.File=${catalina.base}/logs/application.log
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{HH:mm:ss, SSS} %t [%p] %c{1} - %m%n

 # CONSOLE is set to be a ConsoleAppender using a PatternLayout.
log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} [%p] %m%ne
```

In the persistence.xml:

```
...
    <properties>
        <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINE"/>           
    </properties>
```

Comment: Have you ever tried this with log4j2 ?

Answer (score 4):

Eclipse Link doesn't use log4j by default. This page describes how you can integrate it:

http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Foundation/Logging

Comment: I am getting org.eclipse.persistence.logging.CommonsLoggingSessionLog ClassNotFoundexception, any jars as dependencies ? Please help

Answer (score 0):

See,

http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Logging

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you initialize EclipseLink logging facilities (by doing some action that normally requires logging) before you add your own handlers to the system. I think that EclipseLink overrides the root logger settings and maybe destroys your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using EclipseLink with JBoss AS7 i recommend ***Step 5: Configure EclipseLink logging (optional)*** in the following page on how to get logging correct:

https://community.jboss.org/wiki/HowToUseEclipseLinkWithAS7

In short you will need to:

1. Add *JBossLogger.java* file to you project (attached to the article)
2. Add dependency to library *jboss-logging*
3. Set property ***eclipselink.logging.logger*** in *persistence.xml*